# Onclick event is not working in UWP (Window 10) using (Cordova)

Tags: cordova, uwp

onclick is not working in html tags in t7 template.
like:

```
<a onclick="myFunction()">Click me</a>
<script>
function myFunction(){ 
//Some code 
}
</script>
```

After rendring the template i add dynamically javascript in onclick then its working like that

```
<a onclick="javascript:myFunction()">Click me</a>
<script>
function myFunction(){ 
//Some code 
}
</script>
```

Need to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
StartPage="ms-appx-web:///www/index.html"
```

in package.windows10.appxmanifest file

```
<Application Id="Xyz" StartPage="ms-appx-web:///www/index.html">
```